# How to install local package with conda

Tags: python, conda, conda-build

I have a local python project called `jive` that I would like to use in an another project. My current method of using `jive` in other projects is to activate the conda env for the project, then move to my `jive` directory and use `python setup.py install`. This works fine, and when I use `conda list`, I see everything installed in the env including `jive`, with a note that `jive` was installed using pip.

But what I really want is to do this with full conda. When I want to use `jive` in another project, I want to just put `jive` in that projects `environment.yml`.

So I did the following:

1. write a simple `meta.yaml` so I could use conda-build to build `jive` locally
2. build jive with `conda build .`
3. I looked at the tarball that was produced and it does indeed contain the `jive` source as expected
4. In my other project, add jive to the dependencies in `environment.yml`, and add 'local' to the list of channels.
5. create a conda env using that environment.yml.

When I activate the environment and use `conda list`, it lists all the dependencies including `jive`, as desired. But when I open python interpreter, I cannot `import jive`, it says there is no such package. (If use `python setup.py install`, I can import it.)
**How can I fix the build/install so that this works?**

Here is the meta.yaml, which lives in the `jive` project top level directory:

```
package:
  name: jive
  version: "0.2.1"

source:
  path: .

build:
  script: python -m pip install --no-deps --ignore-installed .

requirements:
  host:
     - python>=3.5
     - pip
     - setuptools
  run:
     - python>=3.5
     - numpy
     - pandas
     - scipy
     - seaborn
     - matplotlib
     - scikit-learn
     - statsmodels
     - joblib
     - bokeh

test:
  imports: jive
```

And here is the output of `conda build .`

```
No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.16
WARNING:conda_build.metadata:No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.16
Adding in variants from internal_defaults
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from internal_defaults
Adding in variants from /Users/thomaskeefe/.conda/conda_build_config.yaml
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from /Users/thomaskeefe/.conda/conda_build_config.yaml
Attempting to finalize metadata for jive
INFO:conda_build.metadata:Attempting to finalize metadata for jive
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
BUILD START: ['jive-0.2.1-py310_0.tar.bz2']
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pla


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    bzip2:           1.0.8-h1de35cc_0
    ca-certificates: 2021.10.26-hecd8cb5_2
    certifi:         2021.5.30-py310hecd8cb5_0
    libcxx:          12.0.0-h2f01273_0
    libffi:          3.3-hb1e8313_2
    ncurses:         6.3-hca72f7f_2
    openssl:         1.1.1m-hca72f7f_0
    pip:             21.2.4-py310hecd8cb5_0
    python:          3.10.0-hdfd78df_3
    readline:        8.1.2-hca72f7f_1
    setuptools:      58.0.4-py310hecd8cb5_0
    sqlite:          3.37.0-h707629a_0
    tk:              8.6.11-h7bc2e8c_0
    tzdata:          2021e-hda174b7_0
    wheel:           0.37.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
    xz:              5.2.5-h1de35cc_0
    zlib:            1.2.11-h4dc903c_4

Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
Copying /Users/thomaskeefe/Documents/py_jive to /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/work/
source tree in: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/work
export PREFIX=/opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pla
export BUILD_PREFIX=/opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_build_env
export SRC_DIR=/opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/work
Processing $SRC_DIR
  DEPRECATION: A future pip version will change local packages to be built in-place without first copying to a temporary directory. We recommend you use --use-feature=in-tree-build to test your packages with this new behavior before it becomes the default.
   pip 21.3 will remove support for this functionality. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7555.
Building wheels for collected packages: jive
  Building wheel for jive (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for jive (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for jive: filename=jive-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl size=46071 sha256=b312955cb2fd917bc4e684a575407b884190680f2dddad7fcb9ac25e5b290fc9
  Stored in directory: /private/tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-rbpkt2an/wheels/15/68/82/4ed7cd246fbc4c72cf764b425a03230247589bd2394a7e457b
Successfully built jive
Installing collected packages: jive
Successfully installed jive-0.2.1

Resource usage statistics from building jive:
   Process count: 3
   CPU time: Sys=0:00:00.3, User=0:00:00.5
   Memory: 53.7M
   Disk usage: 50.4K
   Time elapsed: 0:00:06.1


Packaging jive
INFO:conda_build.build:Packaging jive
INFO conda_build.build:build(2289): Packaging jive
Packaging jive-0.2.1-py310_0
INFO:conda_build.build:Packaging jive-0.2.1-py310_0
INFO conda_build.build:bundle_conda(1529): Packaging jive-0.2.1-py310_0
compiling .pyc files...
number of files: 70
Fixing permissions
INFO :: Time taken to mark (prefix)
        0 replacements in 0 files was 0.06 seconds
TEST START: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/osx-64/jive-0.2.1-py310_0.tar.bz2
Adding in variants from /var/folders/dd/t85p2jdn3sd11bsdnl7th6p00000gn/T/tmp4o3im7d1/info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from /var/folders/dd/t85p2jdn3sd11bsdnl7th6p00000gn/T/tmp4o3im7d1/info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml
INFO conda_build.variants:_combine_spec_dictionaries(234): Adding in variants from /var/folders/dd/t85p2jdn3sd11bsdnl7th6p00000gn/T/tmp4o3im7d1/info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml
Renaming work directory '/opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/work' to '/opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/work_moved_jive-0.2.1-py310_0_osx-64'
INFO:conda_build.utils:Renaming work directory '/opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/work' to '/opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/work_moved_jive-0.2.1-py310_0_osx-64'
INFO conda_build.utils:shutil_move_more_retrying(2091): Renaming work directory '/opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/work' to '/opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/work_moved_jive-0.2.1-py310_0_osx-64'
shutil.move(work)=/opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/work, dest=/opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/work_moved_jive-0.2.1-py310_0_osx-64)
INFO:conda_build.utils:shutil.move(work)=/opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/work, dest=/opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/work_moved_jive-0.2.1-py310_0_osx-64)
INFO conda_build.utils:shutil_move_more_retrying(2098): shutil.move(work)=/opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/work, dest=/opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/work_moved_jive-0.2.1-py310_0_osx-64)
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    blas:              1.0-mkl
    bokeh:             2.4.2-py39hecd8cb5_0
    bottleneck:        1.3.2-py39he3068b8_1
    brotli:            1.0.9-hb1e8313_2
    ca-certificates:   2021.10.26-hecd8cb5_2
    certifi:           2021.10.8-py39hecd8cb5_2
    cycler:            0.11.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
    fonttools:         4.25.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
    freetype:          2.11.0-hd8bbffd_0
    giflib:            5.2.1-haf1e3a3_0
    intel-openmp:      2021.4.0-hecd8cb5_3538
    jinja2:            3.0.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
    jive:              0.2.1-py310_0            local
    joblib:            1.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
    jpeg:              9d-h9ed2024_0
    kiwisolver:        1.3.1-py39h23ab428_0
    lcms2:             2.12-hf1fd2bf_0
    libcxx:            12.0.0-h2f01273_0
    libffi:            3.3-hb1e8313_2
    libgfortran:       3.0.1-h93005f0_2
    libpng:            1.6.37-ha441bb4_0
    libtiff:           4.2.0-h87d7836_0
    libwebp:           1.2.0-hacca55c_0
    libwebp-base:      1.2.0-h9ed2024_0
    llvm-openmp:       12.0.0-h0dcd299_1
    lz4-c:             1.9.3-h23ab428_1
    markupsafe:        2.0.1-py39h9ed2024_0
    matplotlib:        3.5.0-py39hecd8cb5_0
    matplotlib-base:   3.5.0-py39h4f681db_0
    mkl:               2021.4.0-hecd8cb5_637
    mkl-service:       2.4.0-py39h9ed2024_0
    mkl_fft:           1.3.1-py39h4ab4a9b_0
    mkl_random:        1.2.2-py39hb2f4e1b_0
    munkres:           1.1.4-py_0
    ncurses:           6.3-hca72f7f_2
    numexpr:           2.8.1-py39h2e5f0a9_0
    numpy:             1.21.2-py39h4b4dc7a_0
    numpy-base:        1.21.2-py39he0bd621_0
    olefile:           0.46-pyhd3eb1b0_0
    openssl:           1.1.1m-hca72f7f_0
    packaging:         21.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
    pandas:            1.3.5-py39h743cdd8_0
    patsy:             0.5.2-py39hecd8cb5_0
    pillow:            8.4.0-py39h98e4679_0
    pip:               21.2.4-py39hecd8cb5_0
    pyparsing:         3.0.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0
    python:            3.9.7-h88f2d9e_1
    python-dateutil:   2.8.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
    pytz:              2021.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
    pyyaml:            6.0-py39hca72f7f_1
    readline:          8.1.2-hca72f7f_1
    scikit-learn:      1.0.2-py39hae1ba45_0
    scipy:             1.7.3-py39h8c7af03_0
    seaborn:           0.11.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
    setuptools:        58.0.4-py39hecd8cb5_0
    six:               1.16.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
    sqlite:            3.37.0-h707629a_0
    statsmodels:       0.13.0-py39hca72f7f_0
    threadpoolctl:     2.2.0-pyh0d69192_0
    tk:                8.6.11-h7bc2e8c_0
    tornado:           6.1-py39h9ed2024_0
    typing_extensions: 3.10.0.2-pyh06a4308_0
    tzdata:            2021e-hda174b7_0
    wheel:             0.37.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
    xz:                5.2.5-h1de35cc_0
    yaml:              0.2.5-haf1e3a3_0
    zlib:              1.2.11-h4dc903c_4
    zstd:              1.4.9-h322a384_0

Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working...
ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::intel-openmp-2021.4.0-hecd8cb5_3538, defaults/osx-64::llvm-openmp-12.0.0-h0dcd299_1
  path: 'lib/libiomp5.dylib'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'bin/webpinfo'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'bin/webpmux'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'include/webp/decode.h'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'include/webp/encode.h'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'include/webp/mux.h'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'include/webp/mux_types.h'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'include/webp/types.h'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'lib/libwebp.7.dylib'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'lib/libwebp.a'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'lib/libwebp.dylib'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'lib/libwebpdecoder.3.dylib'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'lib/libwebpdecoder.a'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'lib/libwebpdecoder.dylib'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'lib/libwebpmux.3.dylib'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'lib/libwebpmux.a'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'lib/libwebpmux.dylib'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'lib/pkgconfig/libwebp.pc'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'lib/pkgconfig/libwebpdecoder.pc'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'lib/pkgconfig/libwebpmux.pc'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'share/man/man1/cwebp.1'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'share/man/man1/dwebp.1'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'share/man/man1/webpinfo.1'


ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0, defaults/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  path: 'share/man/man1/webpmux.1'



done
Executing transaction: ...working...
ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/llvm-openmp-12.0.0-h0dcd299_1/lib/libiomp5.dylib
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libiomp5.dylib




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/bin/webpinfo
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/bin/webpinfo




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/bin/webpmux
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/bin/webpmux




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/include/webp/decode.h
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/include/webp/decode.h




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/include/webp/encode.h
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/include/webp/encode.h




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/include/webp/mux.h
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/include/webp/mux.h




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/include/webp/mux_types.h
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/include/webp/mux_types.h




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/include/webp/types.h
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/include/webp/types.h




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/lib/libwebp.7.dylib
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libwebp.7.dylib




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/lib/libwebp.a
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libwebp.a




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/lib/libwebp.dylib
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libwebp.dylib




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/lib/libwebpdecoder.3.dylib
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libwebpdecoder.3.dylib




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/lib/libwebpdecoder.a
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libwebpdecoder.a




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/lib/libwebpdecoder.dylib
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libwebpdecoder.dylib




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/lib/libwebpmux.3.dylib
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libwebpmux.3.dylib




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/lib/libwebpmux.a
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libwebpmux.a




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/lib/libwebpmux.dylib
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libwebpmux.dylib




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/.condatmp/1018f8ab-87a7-4fa8-a41c-4c14cc77cfff
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/pkgconfig/libwebp.pc




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/.condatmp/e3701fae-f2cd-44e9-9dc6-c71f499cd2c2
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/pkgconfig/libwebpdecoder.pc




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/.condatmp/0f4bcf50-01e5-404d-b1a4-8a87d45c22c5
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/pkgconfig/libwebpmux.pc




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/share/man/man1/cwebp.1
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/share/man/man1/cwebp.1




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/share/man/man1/dwebp.1
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/share/man/man1/dwebp.1




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/share/man/man1/webpinfo.1
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/share/man/man1/webpinfo.1




ClobberWarning: Conda was asked to clobber an existing path.
  source path: /opt/miniconda3/pkgs/libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0/share/man/man1/webpmux.1
  target path: /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/share/man/man1/webpmux.1





    Installed package of scikit-learn can be accelerated using scikit-learn-intelex.
    More details are available here: https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex

    For example:

        $ conda install scikit-learn-intelex
        $ python -m sklearnex my_application.py



done
export PREFIX=/opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol
export SRC_DIR=/opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/test_tmp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/jive_1642185595622/test_tmp/run_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import jive
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jive'
import: 'jive'
Tests failed for jive-0.2.1-py310_0.tar.bz2 - moving package to /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/broken
WARNING:conda_build.build:Tests failed for jive-0.2.1-py310_0.tar.bz2 - moving package to /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/broken
WARNING conda_build.build:tests_failed(2970): Tests failed for jive-0.2.1-py310_0.tar.bz2 - moving package to /opt/miniconda3/conda-bld/broken
TESTS FAILED: jive-0.2.1-py310_0.tar.bz2
```

**EDIT: I added a `test:` section to the meta.yaml as merv suggested.**

Comment: Considering [adding a `test:` section](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#python-imports) so that the `conda-build` command verifies there are no import issues with the build. That would help us discern whether the issue is with the package build or with the installation.

Comment: Thanks, have just edited the post with result from that. It fails to `import jive`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate error is that the build is generating a Python 3.10 version, but when testing Conda doesn't recognize any constraint on the Python version, and creates a Python 3.9 environment.

I think the main issue is that `python >=3.5` is only a valid constraint when doing `noarch` builds, which this is not. That is, once a package builds with a given Python version, the version must be constrained to exactly that version (up through minor). So, in this case, the package is built with Python 3.10, but it reports in its metadata that it is compatible with all versions of Python 3.5+, which simply isn't true because Conda Python packages install the modules into Python-version-specific `site-packages` (e.g., `lib/python-3.10/site-packages/jive`).

Typically, Python versions are controlled by either the `--python` argument given to `conda-build` or a matrix supplied by the `conda_build_config.yaml` file (see [documentation on "*Build variants*"](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/variants.html)).

Try adjusting the `meta.yaml` to something like

```yaml
package:
  name: jive
  version: "0.2.1"

source:
  path: .

build:
  script: python -m pip install --no-deps --ignore-installed .

requirements:
  host:
     - python
     - pip
     - setuptools
  run:
     - python
     - numpy
     - pandas
     - scipy
     - seaborn
     - matplotlib
     - scikit-learn
     - statsmodels
     - joblib
     - bokeh
```

If you want to use it in a Python 3.9 environment, then use `conda build --python 3.9 .`.